# cover art for vinyl LP, correct settings in application to do artwork?

Tags: art, vinyl

cover art for vinyl LP cover, correct settings in application to do artwork?

adobe indesign, photoshop

I'm the one who supposed to do artwork for cover of LP (vinyl)

What settings for artwork pixels, etc to get job done properly for publishing/print

I'm sure many times it was done with success! I could not find definite answer on internet yet.
The closest one was no less then 3600 x 3600 pixels (What if I'll use more, 4000 for example)

One more time:
Please help me to set correctly
Adobe Photoshop and inDesign for artwork cover for LP vinyl 12"

Comment: All those comments you spammed in the answer below, that's your answer! Learn how to read, it's all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the disks and their jackets are ordered from a company which makes them professionally. They surely give a template for the job and a written guide. How  they could otherwise get customers?

ADD: There are plenty of vinyl pressing and record packaging companies. Their quidance seems to be ok, but they expect some knowledge of the print preparing vocabulary such as CMYK, spot colors, bleed, 300 DPI,...

Many of them have only PDF templates. It has all needed limits such as edge safety margins for you, their own print marks and of course, the right size. They cannot use normal rectangular page print marks, because the cardboard pieces and papers are not rectangular. Some of them say "include the template AS IS, do not move or edit anything! Add your texts and images as new layers". Some allow exactly one flattened artwork layer. Others say "delete all parts of the template after you are ready".

If you are going to make all work in Photoshop and you have a PDF template, open it in Photoshop. Use the following settings:

When opening, set Crop to Media Box, Resolution to 300 pixels / inch,
Mode to CMYK Color and Bit Depth to 8 bit. This gives to you one layer with transparent background and the file has right pixel dimensions. Rename that layer = Template, do not make any edits to it.

I didn't see any special mentions for color settings other than CMYK. Take into use North American General Purpose preset, you cannot go badly wrong with it in North America. Best printers give to you all needed color settings. ASK! Use proof = working CMYK and prepare not to have as bright colors as you had in RGB mode. Adobe stuff has become industry standard because it shows the final printed color (at least if you have calibrated colors in your system and do not bypass color management)

You can build your texts and images in new layers. Some disc printers do not demand "flatten all to one layer", they let texts stay as vector texts and try even preserve some vector shapes.You must unfortunately give all used fonts.

Nearly all seem to want a layout file for different printable parts. One for the jacket, one for the disk center label etc.... Photoshop PSDs can be passable, if you obey the guidance. It's more than easy to include an inferior screen resolution image which is automatically scaled to the template size. It looks out ok onscreen, but is inferiorly low res, when printed. Allways check the pixel dimensions of inserted images before you insert them. 300 ORIGINAL pixels per one FINAL inch is the minimum.

I recommend to use Illustrator or InDesign because you will get ultracrisp texts. There's no need to give the fonts, if you convert the texts to curves (=outlines). In addition text and image layout is more easily done there. You can keep the PDF template in a non-printable layer on the top to see it all the time.

One disc presser had somehow simpler templates and more straightforward guidance texts:

https://www.discmakers.com/templates/vinyl.asp (no shopping recommendation here, only see and learn)

They have ready to use templates for several common graphics software. If you try them, you see, that they are made for legacy Illustrator, Photoshop, etc... and you probably have new Adobe stuff. Probably they still open ok. Save the work only as your current software version, do not try make legacy PSDs, Ais, indds etc...

If you feel uncomfort with printing jargon, get local help. I bet it's worth the used time and price.